# AttributeError at /tickets/ticket/1/like/ 'str' object has no attribute 'fields'

Tags: django

I have a url that is called when a button is pressed but I am getting an attribute error. The strange thing is I only get the attribute error when I run my app on Heroku, when it is running locally I don't get any errors at all. I have checked and heroku is running my latest code in github so I am really confused as to what is happening here!

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://dm-issuetracker.herokuapp.com/tickets/ticket/1/like/

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.6.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_forms_bootstrap',
 'accounts',
 'tickets',
 'checkout']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /app/templates/base.html, error at line 0
   'str' object has no attribute 'fields'   1 : {% load staticfiles %}
   2 : 
   3 : <html>
   4 : 
   5 : <head>
   6 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   7 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   8 :     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   9 :     <title>IssueTracker{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
   10 :     <link rel="icon" href="media/img/bug.jpg">


Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/tickets/views.py" in ticket_vote
  71.     return render(request, "ticketdetail.html", {'ticket':ticket})

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1040.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  736.                 new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_forms_bootstrap/templatetags/bootstrap_tags.py" in as_bootstrap_inline
  41.     form = _preprocess_fields(form)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_forms_bootstrap/templatetags/bootstrap_tags.py" in _preprocess_fields
  17.     for field in form.fields:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /tickets/ticket/1/like/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

Here is urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import get_tickets, ticket_detail, create_or_edit_ticket, ticket_vote, ticket_vote_list

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', get_tickets, name='get_tickets'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ticket_detail, name = 'ticket_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ticket_vote, name = 'ticket_vote'),
    url(r'^tickets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/like/$', ticket_vote_list, name='ticket_vote_list'),
    url(r'^ticket/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/like/$', ticket_vote, name='ticket_vote'),
    url(r'^new/$', create_or_edit_ticket, name = 'new_ticket'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', create_or_edit_ticket, name = 'edit_ticket')
]
```

urls.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Ticket
from .forms import TicketsForm, TicketCommentForm

def get_tickets(request):
    """
    Create a view that will return a list of tickets that were published and 
    render them to 'issuetrackertickets.html' template
    """
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now
    ())
    return render(request, "issuetrackertickets.html", {'tickets':tickets})

def ticket_detail(request,pk):
    """
    Create a view that will return a single ticket object based on the ticket id 
    and render it to the 'ticketdetail.html' template
    """
    print("ticket detail")
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=pk) 
    ticket.views +=1
    ticket.save()
    # Display comments
    comments = ticket.ticketcomment_set.all().order_by('comment_date')
    # Form for adding a comment
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('submit'):
        comment_form = TicketCommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user.username
            comment.ticket = ticket
            comment.save()
            return redirect(ticket_detail, pk=ticket.pk)
    # Form for upvoting tickets
    elif request.method == 'POST' and not request.POST.get('submit'):
        comment_form = TicketCommentForm()
    else:
        comment_form = TicketCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'ticketdetail.html', {'ticket': ticket, 'comments': comments, 'comment_form': comment_form})

@login_required
def create_or_edit_ticket(request, pk=None):
    """
    Create a view that allows us to create or edit a ticket depending if 
    the tickets id is null or not. 
    """
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=pk) if pk else None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketsForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=ticket)
        if form.is_valid():
            ticket = form.save()
            ticket.author = request.user.username
            return redirect(ticket_detail, ticket.pk)
    else:
        form = TicketsForm(instance=ticket)
    return render(request, "issuetrackerticketform.html", {'form':form})
    
def ticket_vote(request,pk):
    """
    Create a view that will increase the upvotes for the current ticket
    and render it to the 'ticketdetail.html' template
    """
    print("ticket_vote")
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=pk) 
    ticket.upvotes +=1
    ticket.save()
    return render(request, "ticketdetail.html", {'ticket':ticket})
    
def ticket_vote_list(request,pk):
    """
    Create a view that will increase the upvotes for the current ticket in the list
    and render it to the 'ticketdetail.html' template
    """
    print("ticket_vote_list")
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=pk) 
    ticket.upvotes +=1
    ticket.save()
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now
    ())
    return render(request, "issuetrackertickets.html", {'tickets':tickets})
```

models.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Ticket(models.Model):
    """
    Add a ticket
    """
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('BUG', 'Bug'),
        ('NEW_FEATURE', 'New feature')
    )
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('TO_DO', 'To do'),
        ('UNDER_REVIEW', 'Under Review'),
        ('DECLINED', 'Declined'),
        ('PLANNED', 'Planned'),
        ('IN_PROGRESS', 'In Progress'),
        ('COMPLETED', 'Completed')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225,blank=False)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    content = models.TextField()
    ticket_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='BUG', max_length=11)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='TO_DO', max_length=12)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    
class TicketComment(models.Model):
    """Model that can create comments"""
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    comment = models.TextField(blank=False)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)    
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.author
```

Comment: You are not passing `comments` and `comment_form` context variables while executing the `ticket_vote(...)` view function. Probably, you may not need this variable at the moment, but, you must handle the emptiness of these variables in your template as well.

Comment: Thank you so much - I missed that! All is working perfectly now :)